# Parse containedIn query not returning results

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, parse-server

Im trying to write a query that looks in a table and only returns results for objectId's that have been stored in an array.

My array column on the backend:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.current()
let allSelectedPacksArray: NSMutableArray = currentUser?["allSelectedPacks"] as! NSMutableArray
print(allSelectedPacksArray)
```

Andy query:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Pack")
query.order(byAscending: "packName")
query.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: [allSelectedPacksArray])
query.fromLocalDatastore()

if error != nil || objects?.isEmpty == true {
print("theres no objects to be had")
} else if let items = objects {
```

objects is empty and console prints:

```
theres no objects to be had
```

The print(allSelectedPacksArray) returns the following:

```
(
    tW4qPPdKSp,
    HnwTkSwcZc,
    zbhe0Kt59Z
)
```

so the column contains data and it is gettable

when i remove the containedIn line everything works fine.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I haven't used NSMutable array much but that seems to be i had to set the array as.

If i don't cast it as NSMutable array like:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.current()
let allSelectedPacksArray = currentUser?["allSelectedPacks"]
print(allSelectedPacksArray)
```

the console prints:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x60800005a9d0>(
tW4qPPdKSp,
HnwTkSwcZc,
zbhe0Kt59Z
)
)
```

Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the use of square brackets around the array.

remove the [] from [allSelectedPacksArray] and just have allSelectedPacksArray and all works.

This is odd because the code prompts for the brackets. but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is optional as stated in the console and this is from the `?` part of your statement. If you change this to a `!` you will see the expected result.

```
let allSelectedPacksArray = currentUser?["allSelectedPacks"]
```

**should become:**

```
let allSelectedPacksArray = currentUser!["allSelectedPacks"]
```

Comment: Nah this doesn't do anything same result.